Error in Flink process Kafka topic:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
I have a Flink program which must be connected to Kafka topic as a consumer and process it.
I already set Kafka server.properties:
  broker.id=0
  listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
  log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
  zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
  num.network.threads=3
  num.io.threads=8
  socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
  socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
  socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
  log.retention.hours=168
  log.segment.bytes=1073741824
  log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
  log.cleaner.enable=true

Then first I run Zookeeper and then run Kafka server. They are run without any error.
I check that 9092 is open:
 nc -zv localhost 9092

The answer is :
 Connection to localhost (127.0.0.1) 9092 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

Moreover, in the Flink program I have these dependencies:
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>

The program is in the following:
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
  import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.AggregateFunction;
  import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
  import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
  import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
  import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
  import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
  import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
  import java.util.Properties;
  import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
  import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
  public class WordCount {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Set up the streaming execution environment
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
   StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    // Create a DataStream from a source
    DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);
    // Process the stream
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> wordCounts = text
            .flatMap(new Tokenizer())
            .keyBy(value -> value.f0)
            .sum(1);
    // Print the results to the standard output
    wordCounts.print();
    // Execute the job
    env.execute("Flink Streaming Word Count");
    // Kafka properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
    // Create a Kafka consumer
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
            "test",
            new SimpleStringSchema(),
            properties
    );
    // Add the consumer as a source
    DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(consumer);
    // Parse the JSON transaction records and extract transaction amounts
    DataStream<Double> transactionAmounts = stream.map(record -> {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(record);
        return jsonNode.get("tranamount").asDouble();
    });
    // Calculate sum, count, and average over a sliding window of 1 minute
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Double>> result = transactionAmounts
            .timeWindowAll(Time.minutes(1))
            .aggregate(new AggregateFunction<Double, Tuple2<Double, Integer>, 
    Tuple2<String, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<Double, Integer> createAccumulator() {
                    return new Tuple2<>(0.0, 0);
                }
                @Override
                public Tuple2<Double, Integer> add(Double value, Tuple2<Double, Integer> accumulator) {
                    return new Tuple2<>(accumulator.f0 + value, accumulator.f1 + 1);
                }

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, Double> getResult(Tuple2<Double, Integer> accumulator) {
                    double sum = accumulator.f0;
                    int count = accumulator.f1;
                    double average = sum / count;
                    return new Tuple2<>("Sum: " + sum + ", Count: " + count + ", Avg: " + average, average);
                }

                @Override
                public Tuple2<Double, Integer> merge(Tuple2<Double, Integer> a, Tuple2<Double, Integer> b) {
                    return new Tuple2<>(a.f0 + b.f0, a.f1 + b.f1);
                }
            });

    // Print the result to the console
    result.print();

    // Execute the Flink job
    env.execute("Flink Kafka JSON Consumer Example");

   } 

  public static final class Tokenizer implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
    @Override
    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
        // Normalize and split the line into words
        String[] tokens = value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
        // Emit the pairs
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.length() > 0) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<>(token, 1));
            }
        }
    }
   }
  }

Every things seems normal but when I run the program I receive this error:
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Would you please guide me how to solve the problem?
Any help is really appreciated.

Problem solved.
Issue was because of conflict between Flink version and Kafka version. The suitable version is in the following:
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>


Please check port 9999 is open.
I think ConnectException is caused by port 9999, not 9092.
And if port 9999 can be connected, your code will be block at
env.execute("Flink Streaming Word Count");

The code of rest does not have a chance to run.

I don't think so. 9999 is block and still the program is running. With that dependency which I said. nc: connect to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9999 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

It's weird, I copy your code and run it locally, it will block when port 9999 is open, if not it throw ConnectException.
